# Error en método compare de Collections Java

Tags: java, ordenamiento

!Buenas!

Estoy intentando con el método de ordenación de `Collections` sobreescribir el metodo `compare` para que me ordene una lista de coches, **de menor a mayor en kilometros**.

En la **clase principal**, donde tengo el `main`, tengo este código:

```
    case 1:

        System.out.print("¿Quieres ordenar los nombres? S/N: ");
        ordenar = sc.nextLine();

        if(ordenar.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {

            for(Coche lista: listaCoches) {

                System.out.println("----");
                System.out.println(lista.mostrarCoches());
                System.out.println("----");

            }//FIN BUCLE FOR.

        }//FIN CONDICIONAL.
        else {

            Collections.sort(listaCoches, new Comparator() {
                public int compare(Coche c1, Coche c2) {
                    return new Integer(c1.getKilometros()).compareTo(new Integer(c2.getKilometros()));
                }
            });


            for(Coche lista: listaCoches) {

                System.out.println(lista.mostrarCoches());
                System.out.println("-----");
            }
        }
        break;
```

Donde me interesa solucionar esta parte, ya que es la que me da error:

```
Collections.sort(listaCoches, new Comparator() {
 public int compare(Coche c1, Coche c2) {
    return new Integer(c1.getKilometros()).compareTo(new Integer(c2.getKilometros()));
        }
        });
```

Donde me lo señala todo de amarillo, me dice que el método compare no esta siendo utilizado y me lanza este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es la primera vez que utilizo `Collections` y no se muy bien como solucionar esto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tengo reputación suficiente para realizar un comentario,

Al utilizar un Comparator es necesario especificar el tipo de Objeto a comparar,

> new Comparator<Coche>

```
Collections.sort(listaCoches, new Comparator<Coche>() {
 @Override
 public int compare(Coche c1, Coche c2) {
    return new Integer(c1.getKilometros()).compareTo(new 
                 Integer(c2.getKilometros()));             
    }
});
```

Actualmente al instanciar el new Comparator, estás queriendo sobreescribir el método de compare propio, por ende, es necesario especificar la anotación @Override.

Espero que funcione, happy coding !

Comment: Lo he  probado también pero me sigue sin funcionar, me marca lo mismo. Es mas, me indica que elimine el Override

Comment: Prueba a especificar, <Coche> en el comparator

Comment: Funciona! Que fallo mas tonto... Muchas gracias!